# Как использовать unique_ptr как RAII-lock для объектов

Tags: c++

Как использовать для std::unique_ptr для хендлов и указателей применяя кастомные делетеры (не знаю как перевести deleter), понятно.
Но как это следать, если в вместо делетера надо вызвать метод класса(например, &SomeClass::Release)?

Что-то вроде:

```
std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&IADs::Release)> lock(pRoot, &IADs::Release);
```

Это не то, конечно, и рабтает для освобождения ресурса как параметра для делетера.

Возможна ли передача экземпляру объекта при инстанциировании шаблона 2х параметров? (this и указатель на метод).

Я понимаю, что это контейнер, и вроде как не должен решать такие задачи, но вопрос остается.
Напрашиваеться класс-обёртка. Но может есть решение c std::unique_ptr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
std::function<void(IADs*)> deleter{&IADs::Release};
std::unique_ptr<IADs, decltype(fun)> lock{pRoot, deleter};
```

Если этот пример не собирается, значит в компиляторе ошибка. Обновитесь до последнего, либо же попробуйте вот такой код:

```
auto deleter= std::bind(&IADs::Release, std::placeholders::_1);
std::unique_ptr<IADs, decltype(deleter)> lock{pRoot, deleter};
```

---

Вот Вам полный [пример](http://ideone.com/hzMrnJ), с абстрактным классом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class I
{
public:
    virtual void Release() = 0;
};

class IA: public I
{
public:
    void Release() override
    {
        std::cout << "Released";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IA pRoot;
    std::function<void(I*)> deleter{&I::Release};
    std::unique_ptr<I, decltype(deleter)> lock(&pRoot, deleter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я видимо не до конца понятно сформулировал вопрос. Надо, чтобы делетер был вызовом метода самого же объекта.
т.е. `IADs* pRoot`

P.S.: 
VS2013 ругается на первую строку
`'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,IADs *>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,IADs *> *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Ret,IADs *> *'`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovskiy, обновил ответ. Мой код делает именно то, о чём Вы говорите. Вызывает `IADs::Release` на `pRoot`

Comment: да. Ругаеться и на мой. Я не уточнил, что `IADs::Release` это абстрактный метод `ULONG IUnknown() = 0;`. Может в этом дело.
`Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovskiy, обновил ответ с полностью рабочим примером. У меня нет MSVC13, на на 2015 и других компиляторах всё собирается нормально.

Comment: да с std::bind() все работает. Видимо неполная поддержка С++11 в VS2013 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#featurelist) даёт о себе знать.

Спасибо, за такое исчерпывающее внимание к моему вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое (IMHO), написать отдельный класс, для вызова:

```
struct call_release
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator() (T* ptr) const
    {
        ptr->Release();
    }
};

std::unique_ptr< IADs, call_release > ptr( pRoot );
```

Comment: Спасибо, за идею, @Chorkov. Получилось гибридное решение обертки и unique_ptr. Но, надо либо для класса делать класс делать шаблонным и инстациировать  как `std::unique_ptr< IADs, call_release<IADs>> ptr(pRoot);`, либо просто использовать не шаблонный метод у класса делетера `void operator() (IADs* ptr) const`

Comment: Я ошибся. Работает и без шаблонного класса.